# ClassNotFoundException - Didn't find class but class referenced is a method?

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using build tools 30.0.3 and API level 30, with multidex enabled and imported in gradle

I have an Activity which is declared in my manifest like so

```
   <activity
            android:name="com.weare8.android.ui.sponsorHub.watchAndRespond.AWatchAndRespondCongrats"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/App8Theme.noActionBar"/>
```

And specify the same class at the top of the Activity's file:

```
package com.weare8.android.ui.sponsorHub.watchAndRespond
```

I then have a method called "initData" that is called in the Activity's onResume method. The app crashes when it is called with the following stack trace:

```
2021-03-09 13:35:30.362 25909-25909/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.eight.app.stg, PID: 25909
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/weare8/android/ui/sponsorHub/watchAndRespond/AWatchAndRespondCongrats$initData$1$1;
        at com.weare8.android.ui.sponsorHub.watchAndRespond.AWatchAndRespondCongrats.initData(AWatchAndRespondCongrats.kt:71)
        at com.weare8.android.ui.sponsorHub.watchAndRespond.AWatchAndRespondCongrats.onResume(AWatchAndRespondCongrats.kt:51)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1456)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4428)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4470)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.weare8.android.ui.sponsorHub.watchAndRespond.AWatchAndRespondCongrats$initData$1$1" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~VZbIKt-wdKVMzrVi50UpkQ==/com.eight.app.stg-NFHvGS3I4QjJpJmMcbLfLw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~VZbIKt-wdKVMzrVi50UpkQ==/com.eight.app.stg-NFHvGS3I4QjJpJmMcbLfLw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~VZbIKt-wdKVMzrVi50UpkQ==/com.eight.app.stg-NFHvGS3I4QjJpJmMcbLfLw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.weare8.android.ui.sponsorHub.watchAndRespond.AWatchAndRespondCongrats.initData(AWatchAndRespondCongrats.kt:71) 
        at com.weare8.android.ui.sponsorHub.watchAndRespond.AWatchAndRespondCongrats.onResume(AWatchAndRespondCongrats.kt:51) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1456) 
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4428) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4470) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Invalidate cache/Restart does not work, deleting the .idea folder does not work, Clean/rebuild project does not work. I've seen this error before but not for a specific method. I have no idea why this stopped working, seemingly spontaneously. What else can I try?

Edit: crashing method:

```
private fun initData(offer: WatchAndRespondOffer) = with (offer) {

        Interactors.preferences.removedCachedOffer(offer.campaignId!!)

        if (!offer.linkToProductOrDiscountIncentive?.shortInstruction.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            offerTv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            offerTv.text = offer.linkToProductOrDiscountIncentive?.shortInstruction
        }

        val imageToBeDisplayed = if (!offer.ctaImageUri.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            offer.ctaImageUri
        } else {
            offer.coverTileUri
        }


        if (cashIncentive != null && charityDonationIncentive != null) {

            title_description.setText(R.string.watch_and_respond_congrats_description)

            title_first.show()
            title_second.show()
        } else if (charityDonationIncentive != null) {

            title_second.hide()
            title_first.setText(R.string.watch_and_respond_congrats_title_charity)
            title_description.setText(R.string.watch_and_respond_congrats_donation_description)

        } else if (cashIncentive != null) {


            title_second.hide()
            title_first.setText(R.string.watch_and_respond_congrats_title_cash)
            title_description.setText(R.string.watch_and_respond_congrats_description)

        }

        val isUnite = offer.isUniteIncentive?: false

        if (isUnite){
            title_first.hide()
            title_second.hide()
            title_description.hide()
            wellDoneTv.show()

        } else{
            wellDoneTv.hide()
        }

        setupLinkIncentive(offer)

        Glide.with(applicationContext).asBitmap().load(imageToBeDisplayed).into(object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                val width = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels - 40
                val widthRatio = resource.width
                val heightRatio = resource.height.toFloat()
                val height = ((width.toFloat() / widthRatio.toFloat()) * heightRatio).toInt()

                tileIv.layoutParams.height = height
                Glide.with(applicationContext).load(imageToBeDisplayed).apply(RequestOptions().override(width, height).skipMemoryCache(true)).into(tileIv)

            }
        })

    }
```

Comment: Is there anything unusual about `initData()`, like calling it via reflection only, or is it annotated with some third-party library annotation, etc.? It looks like it is not crashing on a specific method itself, but rather on a class defined inside the method.

Comment: Can you post code?

Comment: Edited with body of crashing method

Comment: You were right, the with(offer) was the problem.